# Loading bar while cmd.exe is running

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd, progress-bar

**What I'm trying to do:**

Pass a command to .cmd, show a loading bar while the command executes, exit cmd and display a message box after progress bar is full

**What's happening:**

When I click the button that sends the command, the application hangs, the command is executed, but CMD never exits after it's finished, so the application remains frozen (until I manually close cmd.exe). I also have no idea how to display a loading bar while the command executes. When the loading bar is full, that's when I'll display the message box.

**My code:**

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\"
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.Start();
p.StandardInput.WriteLine(Command_That's_Called);
```

^ Which gets executed upon a button_Click event.

**Things I've tried:**

```
p.WaitForExit(); // still hangs
```

Also threading, but I got an error like "accessed from thread other than one it was created on".

Regarding CMD not closing, I'd just kill it after a certain amount of time, but it the length of time for the command to complete depends on various things.

Comment: When you redirect output, you also have to read it.  If you don't then the program gets stuck.

Comment: How do I do that? At the moment output is being read into a textbox, but it still hangs.

Comment: Add exit code in your command or close it in program.The progress bar may be you can open a new thread and monitor the cmd.exe,but the progress number displayed is a problem because you actually don't know how long it will takes.I suggest you can use a never end progress algorithm,which fast in the beginning but will become more and more slowly and if you don't set it to end it will never come to end.

Comment: What code should I use to exit the CMD after it finished the command?

Comment: And as far as the loading bar goes, I can just output the results from cmd, and once that's finished display the messagebox, but I still don't know how to close cmd after it finishes executing the command.

Comment: `p.Exit()` doesn't work?Or just add `exit` in your command which you try to execute.

Comment: There's p.Kill(), but if I use that, it exits before it even does anything. The command launches an embedded .exe program. Can I specify to the CMD to exit after it finishes its inital command?

Comment: Can you just run the "embedded .exe program" in your process, rather than running cmd?

Comment: I have to pass arguments to the program via cmd, no other way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exit the CMD process after it finished to execute the command, try to add "/C" at the beginning of your process arguments:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C (your arguments)";
```

If you type "cmd /?" in the command prompt, you'll find that "/C: Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates".

About to add a LoadingBar, you need to learn about [BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Got it to work using "/C my script", now going to try and tackle loading bar, thanks!